# Table inside list item vertically shifted in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, layout

I've got a table inside a li. The table is rendered too low in Chrome 31 & Canary 34.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell 0</td>
                    <td>Cell 1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In Firefox 26.0 I get the expected result (table is rendered "on the first line").

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/P8Ua7/

Would you say this is a Chrome bug or is this following a standard?

EDIT: block elements are rendered at the expected position.

Comment: No CSS rules are necessary to achieve the result.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073776/displaytable-in-ulli-to-get-vertical-alignmiddle-of-a-item-produces-chro  ??

Comment: Same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867595/strange-table-margin-behaviour-inside-li-element

Comment: So there is a `display: inline-table`, which solves the issue.. Still, I wonder about the principle behind this.

Comment: I deleted my answer after reading your comment. Maybe this BUG deserves a proper documentation on google.chrome itself. Also, you should self-answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems one can work around this issue by setting the table to `display: inline-table`.

AFAIK, this is a Chromium bug. I opened a [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332198) for it.

Comment: Still an issue 3 years later - "display: inline-table" changes the behavior rather than fixing it though. I would expect it (well, I would expect this from standard behavior...) to just get rid of the blank line above the table, which this _does_ do... but it also moves the bullet point for the list item to the bottom of the table for some reason.